# TransactionRequiredException when updating with Jpa Repository

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data-jpa

On succesfull authentication I'd like to make a call to db to retrieve some additional info but I get:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Executing an update/delete query; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
```

My `successfulAuthentication` method:

```
    @Override
    public void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
        AppUser appUser = userRepo.findByUsername(user.getUsername());

        Port port;
        portRepo.enableExpiredPorts(LocalDateTime.now());
        port = portRepo.checkIfUserHasPort(appUser.getUserId());
        if (port == null) {
            port = portRepo.getOpenPort();
        } else {
            portRepo.extendDuration(port.getPort());
        }
        portRepo.setInUse(appUser.getUserId(), port.getPort());
        //Some unrelated logic
    }
```

Repo that I am calling:

```
@Repository
public interface PortRepo extends JpaRepository<Port, Integer> {

    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "UPDATE Port SET active=1 WHERE expiration<datetime()", nativeQuery = true)
    void enableExpiredPorts(@Param("localDateTime")LocalDateTime localDateTime);

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Port WHERE user_id=:userId", nativeQuery = true)
    Port checkIfUserHasPort(@Param("userId") Long userId);

    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM Port WHERE active=1 LIMIT 1", nativeQuery = true)
    Port getOpenPort();

    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "UPDATE Port SET active=0, user_id=:userId, expiration=datetime('now')  WHERE port=:port", nativeQuery = true)
    void setInUse(@Param("userId") Long userId, @Param("port") int port);

    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "UPDATE Port SET expiration=datetime('now')  WHERE port=:port", nativeQuery = true)
    void extendDuration(@Param("port") int port);
}
```

Adding `@Transactional` annotation didn't help (It was correct one from `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`)

Comment: Adding `@Transactional` to what?

Comment: @M.Deinum I tried both class (that extends `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter`) and  `successfulAuthentication` method

Comment: The `successulAuthentication` is an internal method call so adding `@Transactional` won't help. The easiest is to create another class and move the logic to there and annotate that class (or the method) with `@Transactional`. Or ditch this all together and write an event listener for `AuthenticationSuccessEvent` and then run your logic there. That way you don't have to extend filters etc. and still get the desired behavior (and have it loosy coupled).

Comment: @M.Deinum Thank you so much that works! I guess creating "service" class is good practice after all.

Comment: You can make it even easier with the listener (I actually just wrote an answer for that).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `successulAuthentication` is an internal method call so adding `@Transactional` won't help (as not passing through the proxy).

The easiest is to create another class and move the logic to there and annotate that class (or the method) with `@Transactional`.

```java
@Component
@Transactional
public class AfterAuthenticationService {

  private final UserRepo userRepo;
  private final PortRepo portRepo;

  public AfterAuthenticationService(UserRepo userRepo, PortRepo portRepo) {
    this.userRepo=userRepo;
    this.portRepo=portRepo;
}

  public void onSuccessfulAuthentication(Authentication authentication) {
    User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
    AppUser appUser = userRepo.findByUsername(user.getUsername());

    portRepo.enableExpiredPorts(LocalDateTime.now());
    Port port = portRepo.checkIfUserHasPort(appUser.getUserId());
    if (port == null) {
      port = portRepo.getOpenPort();
    } else {
      portRepo.extendDuration(port.getPort());
    }
    portRepo.setInUse(appUser.getUserId(), port.getPort());
   //Some unrelated logic
  }
}
```

Then in your filter call this service and next the super method.

```java
@Override
public void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
  this.afterAuthenticationService.onSuccessfulAuthentication(authentication);
  super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, chain, authentication);    
}
```

Or ditch this all together and write an event listener for `InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent` and then run your logic there. That way you don't have to extend filters etc. and still get the desired behavior (and have it loosy coupled).

```java
@Component
@Transactional
public class AfterAuthenticationListener {

  private final UserRepo userRepo;
  private final PortRepo portRepo;

  public AfterAuthenticationService(UserRepo userRepo, PortRepo portRepo) {
    this.userRepo=userRepo;
    this.portRepo=portRepo;
}

  @EventListener(InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent.class)
  public void onSuccesfulAuthentication(InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent event) {
    Authentication authentication = event.getAuthentication();
    User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
    AppUser appUser = userRepo.findByUsername(user.getUsername());

    portRepo.enableExpiredPorts(LocalDateTime.now());
    Port port = portRepo.checkIfUserHasPort(appUser.getUserId());
    if (port == null) {
      port = portRepo.getOpenPort();
    } else {
      portRepo.extendDuration(port.getPort());
    }
    portRepo.setInUse(appUser.getUserId(), port.getPort());
   //Some unrelated logic
  }
}
```

With the listener you can now omit your modified filter.

Comment: Intresting I will consider adapting this aproach in the future, and again thank you for your help!